# Changing Name Displayed in Uninstall a Program

Tags: windows-7

I want to know how to change the name of a Program when I go into Uninstall a Program. How would I find it in regedit? Can I change the Publisher and Date as well? Even the Version?

Answer (score 0):

Start regedit32, open HKLM (local machine), go to

```
HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[Product]" \
```

The keys `"DisplayName", "Publisher" and "Install Date"` are what you are looking for.